Shading Artifact
I need help with diagnosing and fixing this shading artifact. Pictured is the model with the shading areas in question along with the mesh. Thank you.

Hello could you please share the object? https://blend-exchange.com/

@moonboots 

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

It's not a shading problem, you have inner faces, as soon as you give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier it makes them surface through the outer faces, so the best is probably to remove them:

Message to Gorgious: Select All by Trait > Interior Faces won't work in that cases as these inner faces are connected to the outer   ;)
